# Capybara and Selenium Web Driver returns `InvalidArgumentError when I try to attach a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, capybara, rspec-rails, dropzone.js

I am working on a Ruby on Rails project that requires multiple file uploads, and I am using the dropzone npm package to achieve this on the client side.

The big issue is this: In my feature tests, I try to attach the files using Capybara but each time there is an error from Selenium Web Driver saying "File Not Found". This is mind-boggling to me because the files I'm trying to attach are there in my `spec/fixtures` directory.

the error:

```bash
Failure/Error: attach_file('spec/fixtures/gradient.txt', class: 'dz-hidden-input', make_visible: true)

     Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidArgumentError:
       File not found: C:/Users/USER/Desktop/RailsProjects/ticketly/spec/fixtures/gradient.txt
```

#### What I have done

The failing test in my creating_ticket_spec.rb file

```rb
scenario 'with multiple attachments', js: true do
    fill_in 'Name', with: 'Add documentation for blink tag'
    fill_in 'Description', with: 'The blink tag has a speed attribute'

    attach_file('spec/fixtures/gradient.txt', class: 'dz-hidden-input', make_visible: true)
    attach_file('spec/fixtures/speed.txt', class: 'dz-hidden-input', make_visible: true)
    attach_file('spec/fixtures/spin.txt', class: 'dz-hidden-input', make_visible: true)

    click_button 'Create Ticket'

    expect(page).to have_content 'Ticket has been created.'

    within('.ticket .attachments') do
      expect(page).to have_content 'speed.txt'
      expect(page).to have_content 'spin.txt'
      expect(page).to have_content 'gradient.txt'
    end
  end
```

My file upload form

```
<%= bootstrap_form_with(model: [project, ticket], local: true, label_errors: true) do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :name %>
  <%= form.text_area :description %>

  <% upload_url = upload_file_project_tickets_path(project) %>
  <div class="dropzone uploader mb-2 dz-hidden-input" data-url="<%= upload_url %>"></div>
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

My dropzone.js file

```js
const { Dropzone } = require('dropzone');
import 'dropzone/dist/dropzone.css';

Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  const uploader = document.querySelector('.uploader');
  if (uploader) {
    const appendAttachment = (signedId) => {
      const input = document.createElement('input');
      input.type = 'hidden';
      input.name = "attachments[]";
      input.value = signedId;
      uploader.parentElement.append(input);
    };

    const csrfTokenTag = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');
    const csrfToken = csrfTokenTag && csrfTokenTag['content'];

    let headers;
    if (csrfToken) {
      headers = {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken
      };
    } else {
      headers = {};
    }

    var myDropzone = new Dropzone('.uploader', {
      url: uploader.dataset.url,
      headers: headers
    });

    myDropzone.on('success', (file, response) => {
      appendAttachment(response.signedId);
    });

    myDropzone.on('addedfile', function (file, xhr, formData) {
      var submit = document.querySelector('input[type=submit]');
      submit.disabled = true;
    });

    myDropzone.on('queuecomplete', function () {
      var submit = document.querySelector('input[type=submit]');
      submit.disabled = false;
    });
  }
});
```

Software versions used

- rails v6.1.7
- Capybara v3.26
- dropzone.js v5.7.6

I'm sorry if the question is too long as a result of the code attachments.

Comment: Your filenames separators appear to be incorrect for the platform you are on (Windows). You may need to convert those when running on Windows.  Also the version of Capybara you are using is massively out of date (4 years old), which version of selenium-webdriver are you using that with?

Comment: Thank  you for your response  I am currently using v. 4.0.0.rc1 of Selenium webdriver